# WAMP server's Adminer login: "Access denied" - for all users

Tags: wampserver, adminer

1. I downloaded `WAMPServer 3.2.0` and installed it on `Windows 10`.
2. I started `PHPMyAdmin`, logged in to the `mysql` database, and
   changed the empty password of 'root' user to a real password.
3. I Started the `Adminer 4.7.5` and tried to log in the `mysql`
   database, with the 'root' user, but failed.

> "Access denied for user 'root'@'localhost' (using password: YES)".

The same thing happens with any other users, too.

What can I do to solve this?

Answer (score 3):

Problem solved:
Right-click on WampServer icon on the system tray, select "Tools" and select "Invert Default DBMS MariaDB <==> MySQL". WampServer restarts, and after this I can login into the "mysql" database with any user.

Comment: That is actually IMORTANT as this simple operation solved my problem I have been trying to come up with a solution for, for the last couple of hours.

Answer (score 2):

As of WAMPServer 3 you get MySQL and mariaDB installed.

So they cannot both run on port 3306, in fact mariadb will listen on 3307 and MySQL will listen on 3308 by default.

So when you run adminer you have to tell it which database server instance you want to access by specifying the port number the database is listening on. You can do this by adding the port to the host `Server Name` field on the login like so:

[image]

Answer (score 1):

Set a password MySQL if empty

run

```
ALTER USER 'userName'@'localhost' IDENTIFIED BY 'New-Password-Here';
```

try to log in adminer as you set